# In the "Foundation" TV series, what is the plan for a civilization that's NOT tyrannical?

Tags: foundation-2021

Harry, at some point, speaks to how his plan is not just a replacement for the current Empire that would eventually become tyrannical but for something better.  Would someone remind me of this plan and result he was referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acknowledging that the TV show diverges from the books somewhat, [the plan](https://asimov.fandom.com/wiki/Seldon_Plan) is never provided in detail, other than that we know that both the First and Second Foundation were part of it, and that the Mule was not.

> The Seldon Plan refers to the plan engineered by Hari Seldon, Yugo Amaryl, Wanda Seldon, and others at the Psychohistorical Project to shorten a projected thirty thousand years of chaos and war following the inevitable collapse of the Galactic Empire to a mere thousand years, leading to the establishment of a Second Empire -- one whose survival and prosperity is assured by psychohistory.
>
> Psychohistory is a scientific theory created by Hari Seldon that can be used to predict the actions of human beings in large social groups. The Psychohistorical Project was created by Emperor Cleon in Prelude to Foundation in hopes of preventing the Empire from falling -- but Seldon knew this was impossible. He and others realized that it was possible to use psychohistory to predict the effects of changes made to the political fabric of the Empire. Using psychohistorical prediction, Seldon and others fashioned a Plan. The particulars of the Plan are never delved into outside of Foundation, but we do know that the plan involves the two Foundations. The First Foundation is the bastion of physical science and political order while the Second Foundation is a covert group of people hidden away who are experts in mentalics and psychohistorical prediction. While not much detail about the Plan is ever given, Asimov makes clear the fact that Seldon anticipated every development of the Foundation up until the arrival of The Mule.

On TV Tropes, this is known as the [Unspoken Plan Guarantee](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UnspokenPlanGuarantee), that the less we know about a plan, the more likely it is to succeed. Within the *Foundation* books, this is actually part of the plan.

> Hari Seldon and his team of psychohistorians set in motion a plan for the next 1000 years. The basic premise of their science is that history can be pretty accurately calculated mathematically, but only if the participants don't know what's supposed to happen, otherwise the calculations would become way too complicated to be feasible. So they specifically tell nobody about the plan.

If people know the details of the plan, they will make decisions based off of that knowledge, which in turn can make the plan no longer work.

Comment: "Acknowledging that the TV show diverges from the books somewhat" <- the understatement of 2024 so far.

Comment: @FB - excellent answer - thanks.  
Not to contradict what you wrote there is something in the dialogue that suggests that certain events must occur (or not occur) otherwise the next Empire with develop much like the current failing one.  Some tidbit of script I'm missing.  I'll hunt the subtitles some more and report back if I find it.

Comment: FOUND IT:
Foundation(TV), 2x2, 2023
Psychohistorians with access to the Plan.  Knowledge of the future applied judiciously and with intent to quietly adjust the Empire's course.
    [Salvor?]Or the First Foundation's, if needed.
Now she gets it. Finally.
    You're talking like Terminus is the enemy.
It isn't. Not yet.  **But power corrupts.
And a Foundation left unchecked becomes Empire all over again.**